# Harry Potter : Molly Weasly's character suddenly strengthened towards the end?

Tags: harry-potter

Molly Weasley, Ron's mother is always portrayed as a kind,motherly character in most of the contexts in the series.An affectionate,but short-tempered woman when it comes to her kids, she is mostly shown to be a home-maker.

Referring to the books of Gilderoy Lockhart for house-hold spells or Falling prey to the Boggart emotionally in The Harry Potter and the order of Phoenix show that she is not a fighter kind of woman as whom she is portrayed towards the end.

Guarding the 'weapon' in the Harry Potter and the Order of Phoenix .

```
She would have written all this to you, but
if the owl had been intercepted you’d all have been in real trouble, and
she can’t say it for herself because she’s on duty tonight.”
“On duty doing what?” said Ron quickly.
“Never you mind, just stuff for the Order,” said Sirius. “
```

or killing of Bellatrix Lestrange, a woman who has a sophisticated knowledge of Dark Arts, who has a record of torturing well-trained aurors(the Longbottoms), who has killed Sirius Black.

```
“No!” Mrs. Weasley cried as a few students ran forward, trying to come to
her aid. “Get back! Get back! She is mine!”
Molly’s curse soared beneath Bellatrix’s outstretched arm and hit her squarely
in the chest, directly over her heart.
```

Sudden change of intensity of the character does not seem fitting. or does it?

Comment: I don't particularly see the two as incompatible. Consider: Dumbledore is "just" a head teacher, not an Auror, not even in government, but is also one of the most powerful wizards in the world. Molly Weasley was part of the Order of the Phoenix, a group specifically dedicated to fighting Voldemort. She'd had plenty of experience in the first Wizarding War. "Homemaker" was Molly's career choice, not a measure of her skill as a witch.

Comment: Molly fell for Gilderoy because he was dashing and handsome: exactly why many of us have celebrity crushes. Dumbledore fell Grindelwald. Being a powerful wizard or witch does not protect one in affairs of the heart. She fell prey to the boggart because she had plenty of fears to prey on. Don't forget that Hermione, who is definitely an able combatant, was unable to overcome the boggart in Lupin's final exam.

Answer (score 9):

You never knew my mother...  To us as children, she was kind, sweet and caring.  One day, however, I broke one of the school rules and was caned as a consequence.

The change my mother went through was astounding.

She descended on the school in full Fury Mode and gave them hell.  The head teacher was summoned, the offending teacher was called at home and ordered back to the school.  She threatened them with every up to and including criminal charges. She put them through the wringer for nearly an hour.  Every attempt from them to defuse or defer the situation was crushed.  Utterly, utterly demolished.

It was an awesome experience and gave me a new found respect for the little woman who'd raised me with such care.

(Of course, she gave me a good clip round the ear when I got home, for getting myself in the situation in the first place but that was well deserved.)

So why did Molly become so powerful?  Honestly, there's no secret to it.  Her family (and specifically) her children were threatened and she stepped in to defend them.

You've probably heard or read it before, that there is nothing a parent won't do for their children.  It sounds like a trite cliché until you become a parent yourself and realise that it's nothing more than the simple truth.